# How to get the vector direction between two (p1, p2)?

Tags: c++, vector, game-physics

I have been working on Unigine and been trying to code a flight program for weeks, I need to find the direction between two dummy nodes so I can use this direction to rotate the wings of the aircraft. Any explanation would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Erm, are you just looking for `P2 - P1`? Because that's how you get the vector going from `P1` to `P2`.

Comment: I don't really get what you problem is. Mathematically, the direction is either `P1 - P2` or `P2 - P1 = -(P1 - P2)`. Are you referring to how you can do this using Unigine specific types?

Comment: Yeah im looking for Unigine functions that allow me to find the direction between two wings of an aircraft. I've applied two dummy nodes at the edges of the wings.

Comment: Do the nodes store positional information?

Comment: Yeah they do. I'm looking for a function between these two nodes so I know which local axes to rotate.

Comment: You won't get much specific help here since Unigine doesn't provide any documentation for unregistered developers. Have you considered asking on their forums?

Comment: Maybe I need some practise, thanks @molbdnilo

Answer (score 2):

First you have to calculate the length of the distance between P1 and P2.

```
distance = abs(P2(y) - P1(y))
```

Then you can use the angular functions to calculate the angle.

```
a = sin(distance / length(P12))
```

[image: Calculation]

Comment: I know this an old answer, but it's also very wrong! You want to use the inverse sine function (asin), since the angle = asin(O / H)

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in the comments, the vector from P1 to P2 is given by P = P2 - P1.

The direction can be attained in two ways.
1. Directly compute angle = tan_inverse( P.y() / P.x() ).

```
In this method however, 1st quadrant and 3rd quadrant are treated in the same way as the signs cancel out.
```

2.You can normalize this vector to get a unit vector. This is the preferred way since it alleviates the quadrant issues.

```
P(normalized) = P / (mod(p))
```

Now you can get the projection of any vector in this direction by just calculating the dot-product by this unit vector.

Answer (score 1):

I just randomly came across this question and therefore it might be useful for someone else to read some more useful information here, regardless of the fact that this question has been asked years ago.
Currently, there is no accepted answer, which could mean that it wasn't very clear what the OP was asking so I'll confront two problems here.

- Finding the direction of a vector

I am not very fluent in C++ so I'll
go one abstraction below and write C. Consider the following function

```
double get_vector_direction (vector v)
{
    return atan2(v.q.y - v.p.y, v.q.x - v.p.x); /* atan(ratio) */
}
```

As simple as this! Also, I like to define vectors this way:

```
typedef struct POINT { double x, y; } point;
typedef struct VECTOR { point p, q; } vector;
```

the `atan` family of functions returns the inverse tangent and this function returns the direction of a vector, which is the measure of the angle it makes with a horizontal line (in radians).
There is a diagram in the answers here that shows the horizontal line as the x component of a vector. It's a simplistic implementation of a Cartesian to Polar coordinates conversion.

- Finding the distance between the initial and terminal point

You may also want to know the magnitude of the vector, which could be obtained using the distance formula: `sqrt(pow(v.q.x-v.p.x, 2)+pow(v.q.y-v.p.y, 2));`

The two functions make up `direction()` and `distance()` which are the two most essential functions when dealing with algebra during game development. I would also recommend `vectoradd` and maybe even `vectorsub` and of course, `radtodeg` to convert radians to degrees if the angle is to be showed to the player.

Answer (score 0):

If under the *direction* you mean angle w.r.t. an **arbitrary** vector (let it be (p1,p3)), then you can calculate the angle using:

`angle = arcos( (p1,p2) * (p1,p3) / (modulus((p1,p2)) * modulus((p1,p3)) ))`

where `*` is the dot product. The angle will be in radians. To change it to degrees you can multiply it by `180/PI` (PI=3.1415926...). Modulus is length of vector: 
`modulus((p1,p2))=square root((p1,p2) * (p1,p2)).`

The answer is rather about math than C++ but the implementation of the simple formula is straightforward.

Comment: I'm looking for direction. Something like (1.70908 e, 1, -1), not angles. Do you've any idea on finding the direction between two vectors on Unigine? a simple engine.game.(function) perhaps?

Comment: I am not familiar with game engines. If you are not looking for angle but for a vector between two points given in Cartesian coordinates then **p2** - **p1** =(p2_x-p1_x, p2_y-p1_y, p2_z-p1_z) would suffice.