# Vector directions of a hexagon's vertexes

Tags: c#, loops, optimization

I'm trying to get the directions from the center of a hexagon to it's vertexes. But I just can't figure out how to do it via a for loop, so I just made a switch statement and a bunch of cases.

Maybe it's because I'm tired, maybe because I'm a relative novice... the reason doesn't matter.

Can anybody help me formulate this piece of code properly?

```
Vector2 dir;
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                dir = new Vector2(0, 3);
                break;
            case 1:
                dir = new Vector2(0, -3);
                break;
            case 2:
                dir = new Vector2(2, 1);
                break;
            case 3:
                dir = new Vector2(2, -1);
                break;
            case 4:
                dir = new Vector2(-2, -1);
                break;
            case 5:
                dir = new Vector2(-2, 1);
                break;
        }
}
```

Thanks a bunch!

Edit: Clarification

Thanks for all your suggestions, but what I was really looking for is something along the lines:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    dir = new Vector2(f(i), g(i));
    //Code 
}
```

Where *f(i)* is a function that gives the required x coordinate and *g(i)* gives the required y coordinate.
If something like that is even possible.

The for loop is neccessary because of the code following dir assignment.

Comment: If you have a set of k vertices on a 2d plane, you can calculate the centroid by dividing the sum of the coordinates by k. You won't need a `switch` for this. From there, calculating the vector from a vertex is pretty simple - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564229/how-to-get-the-vector-direction-between-two-p1-p2

Answer (score 1):

A hexagon with radius 2 and sides 2 with flat sides on top and bottom

```
List<Vector> vertices = new List<Vector>() {
                new Vector(-1,Math.Sqrt(3)),
                new Vector(1, Math.Sqrt(3)),
                new Vector(2, 0),
                new Vector(1, -1 * Math.Sqrt(3)),
                new Vector(-1, -1 * Math.Sqrt(3)),
                new Vector(-2, 0)
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify that code by removing the for and the switch, like this:

```
Vector2 dir;
dir = new Vector2(0, 3);
dir = new Vector2(0, -3);
dir = new Vector2(2, 1);
dir = new Vector2(2, -1);
dir = new Vector2(-2, -1);
dir = new Vector2(-2, 1);
```

That's not a regular hexagon, by the way, I'm sure you know.

Comment: I actually have some code after the in the for loop as well, so that's a must. But thanks anyway.

Comment: In that case if your first point is at (x,y), the neighbouring point, 60 degrees away, is at x'=xSin60-yCos60 and y'=xCos60+ySin60. To get the next point use 120 degrees. Or google rotation matrix.

Answer (score 0):

> In that case if your first point is at (x,y), the neighbouring point, 60 degrees away, is at x'=xSin60-yCos60 and y'=xCos60+ySin60. To get the next point use 120 degrees. -- Graham

That solved it. I completely forgot about trigonometric functions ... Thanks :)